# Photoshop JSX Script to change layer text dynamically

Tags: extendscript, photoshop-script

I would like to dynamically change the text of a layer in photoshop and export it in PNG format.
However I cannot figure out a way to pass arguments to my jsx script.
I run the following command but the parameter "layer text" is not passed to the jsx script.

**arguments.length** is always **0**.

```
ExtendScript\ Toolkit -run ps.jsx "layer text"
```

ps.jsx

```
#target photoshop
// debug level: 0-2 (0:disable, 1:break on error, 2:break at beginning)
$.level = 1;
var doc = app.open(new File('image001.psd'));
app.activeDocument.artLayers[0].textItem.contents = arguments[0];   
var file = new File("./PhotoshopLayers/image.png");
var saveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
doc.saveAs(file, saveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to pass arguments via estk commandline

but I occasionally use [subtleGradient/node-photoshop: Control Adobe Photoshop and After Effects from Node.js](https://github.com/subtleGradient/node-photoshop) to doing similar issue.

here is an example

install nodejs then

```
cd ~/Desktop; mkdir test
$ npm install photoshop
```

write app.js

```
// ~/Desktop/test/app.js
function main(){
  var doc = app.open(new File('~/Desktop/test/image001.psd'));
  app.activeDocument.artLayers[0].textItem.contents = arguments[0];
  var file = new File("~/Desktop/test/PhotoshopLayers/image.png");
  var saveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  doc.saveAs(file, saveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
  return file
}

var photoshop = require("photoshop");
photoshop.invoke(main, [process.argv[2]], function (e,r) {
  if (!e) {
    console.log(r);
  }
})


$ node app.js "layer text"
```

thank you
mg